# Dynamically get n'th element of vector in Simulink

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, element, simulink

I have a vector [-1 1 -4 9 7] stored in a constants block. I also have signal which contains a scalar which is determined from other parts of my Simulink code. Let's call that scalar, 'n'. How do I extract the n'th element of my vector?
Example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution I can think of is making a custom block and just adding a [Multiport Switch](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/multiportswitch.html) to it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it not possible using default Simulink blocks? I would strongly prefer to do it this way. Failing that, is it possible to elaborate a bit more on how to create the custom block and how it should interact with the Multiport switch? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @MatthewJames ah, that is for tydiness only. Multiport Switch is a default SImulink. You can just make "functions" by putting them inside a subsystem, that is what I meant.

Comment: Would you mind kindly showing me a block diagram of how this will work - or even better an extremely simple version of this working? I can't seem to figure it out :( thanks so much

Comment: Its just a thing to have simulink models tidy. See the tutorial: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/subsystems.html

Comment: Thank you again for your input. I've managed to solve the problem with a multi switch block like you recommended. However, I have an additional complication. The number 'n' is a "variable-size mode", and the multi switch will always output an error. Can you think of a way to solve this?

Thank you :)

Comment: And how would you define  a switch with variable size input? if `n` is `[3 1 51 2 5 1 1 1 ]`, what is the output? You are askign a different question so I suggest you do so in SO, but you will need to define the behaviour you want

Comment: Oh! I finally get it! I thought variable size meant that that actual value of n can change. Instead it means that the size of the vector/matrix/etc changes. Easy fix! I get it :) Thank you so much.

Comment: I have one last final question about something different but related. I now need to extract an element of a matrix (say [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]) and I have the row and column number (say 2,3). How can I use multi-port switch to do this? Thanks again for all your continuous help.

Comment: I have no idea if it works with a multiport swicth, as what it does is connect one signal to the output. maybe you can create linear indices instead of subscripts.